# Nokogiri methods question (HTML)

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I would like to find specific html tags using nokogiri.
For example - I would like to find all the  tags in a page I got, and all the  tags in this page. Is it possible?

Comment: Having "question" in the question title is redundant. Every question on Stack Overflow is a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding every tag in a page is easy.

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<EOT
<html>
  <head>
    <title> the title </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>the paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.search('*').each do |n|
  puts n.name
end

>> html
>> head
>> title
>> body
>> p
```

Comment: .search was what I was looking for. Thanks ! :) P.S - Any chance there is a reference page for such methods? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Both Nokogiri and XPath are documented, so I'm not sure which you mean. Nokogiri has a good mail-list called Nokogiri-Talk for direct questions to the developers.